# Laravel queue supervisor doesn't reread the updates

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

I use Laravel's queues mostly for API jobs, I store the API token in database, everything works okay until the token is needed to be refreshed.

For some reason queue doesn't reread the new token from database. I guess it is cached somehow, but `php artisan cache:clear` doesn't change anything. I run the test with the commands and queue. If I dump the token in the command, it is shown updated, but queue shows the old token.

`supervisorctl restart appname` fixes the issue, but I want to make it work without restarting the queue. Any tips?

Comment: `queue:restart`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Queue workers are long-lived processes and store the booted application state in memory. As a result, they will not notice changes in your code base after they have been started. So, during your deployment process, be sure to restart your queue workers.

```
php artisan queue:restart
```